# How to calculate the radius of gyration (Rg) and the molar mass from light scattering data (Rθ and θ/degree)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

I have a homework problem that I don’t have a solution for, so I would like understand how to solve it and to know if my suggested way of solving it is on the right track. The problem is as following:

> A polysaccharide was analyzed by light scattering at several angles ($\theta$), and the following data were at hand:
>
> 1. the system constant $K = 2 \times 10^{-8}$,
> 2. the concentration is $2.5~\mathrm{mg/mL}$,
> 3. the effective wavelength $\lambda = 400~\mathrm{nm}$,
> 4. the second virial coefficient is assumed to be $0$ (meaning that no correction is needed for the concentration dependence).
>
> Calculate the molar mass and the radius of gyration for the polysaccharide.

We are also given the following information, where I think $R_\theta$ is the measured Rayleigh ratio, and $\theta$ is the scattering angle in degrees:

> \begin{array}{rr}
> R_{\theta}& \theta\\\hline
> 5 & 60\\
> 4 & 90\\
> 3.33&120
> \end{array}

From the lectures I was given the following equation to find the molar mass and $R_\mathrm{g}$:

$$ 
\frac{K \times C}{R_\theta}
  = \frac{1}{M} \left( 1 + \frac{16\pi^2}{3\lambda} R_\mathrm{g} \times 
     \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2 \right)
$$

I am unsure if the way I think is correct — and I don’t really understand all the steps. But here is what I think I have to do, or at least how to starts:

1. extrapolate to zero concentration to account for large molecules (polysaccharide) and non-ideal solution. To do so I think I have to plot $\frac{K \times C}{R_\theta}$ against $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2$.
2. From this the plot I get the linear equation $y = ax + b$ which I can use to:

   - Find molar mass because: $y - \text{intercept} = \frac{1}{M}$
   - Find $R_\mathrm{g}$ because: $\frac{\text{slope}}{y - \text{intercept}} = R_\mathrm{g}$
3. I read somewhere that I should make some sort of a second graph from the first one, in order to remove the $\frac{1}{M}$ part of the equation, and thus, I can somehow calculate $R_\mathrm{g}$, but I don't understand this.

**My Questions**:

- Am I generally on the right track here?
- What units do I get the molecular mass in from the above equation? Is it KDa?
- I think I get $R_\mathrm{g}$ value in nm?